# notepad++ умная замена

Tags: notepad++, форматирование

на wiki принята такая система

```
{| class="article-table"
|Мир-кузня
|Люциус 
|-
|Орудийные щиты
|180 мм

|}
```

что отобразится как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

имеется исходный текст

> Мир-кузня: Луциус
>
> Экипаж танка: Чушки

то есть есть необходимость подменить `:` на перенос строки и `|`

и начало строки на `|`

имеем

```
Мир-кузня: Луциус 

Экипаж танка: Чушки
```

хотим получить

```
|Мир-кузня
|Луциус
|-
|Экипаж танка
|Чушки
```

Comment: У вас `npp` это сокращение от `notepad++`?

Comment: да. общепринято же

Comment: я не знаю код переноса строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `^` на `|` - меняем начало строки на `|`, получаем:

```
|Мир-кузня: Луциус 
|
|Экипаж танка: Чушки
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) `:\s` на \r\| - меняем двоеточие с пробелом на перевод строки и `|`, получаем:

```
|Мир-кузня
|Луциус 
|
|Экипаж танка
|Чушки
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) `\|\r` на `\|\-` - меняем `|` на `|-`, получаем:

```
|Мир-кузня
|Луциус 
|-
|Экипаж танка
|Чушки
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FrDj1yN.png]

Comment: мм. все равно не вписывается в проблему. как изменить 

    Мир-кузня: Луциус
на |Мир-кузня
|Люциус 
|-
|Орудийные щиты
|180 мм
    Экипаж танка: Чушки
 на

Comment: что то неладное http://i.imgur.com/Vm6Ew8M.png

Comment: @des1roer выберите не расширенный режим, а регулярное выражение и новые строки

Comment: да нуна. вы маг. то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Исходные данные:

```
Мир-кузня: Луциус

Экипаж танка: Чушки
```

Меняем `\n+` на `\n-\n`

```
Мир-кузня: Луциус
-
Экипаж танка: Чушки
```

Далее `: *` на `\n`

```
Мир-кузня
Луциус
-
Экипаж танка
Чушки
```

Заканчиваем заменой `^` на `|`

```
|Мир-кузня
|Луциус
|-
|Экипаж танка
|Чушки
```

*За отсутсвием Notepad++ проверял в Sublime Text.*

Comment: по ходу у них разный синтаксис. не работает

Answer (score 0):

> я не знаю код переноса строки – des1roer 2 мин. назад

В notepad++ есть "расширенная" замена, поддерживающая перенос строки.
Есть поддержка регулярных выражений.
Перенос строки — \r.